# Node.js promises and asynchronous exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, asynchronous, promise

I intensively use Promises for wrapping asynchronous code using "promise" (but also tried "bluebird") npm module. And I am not surprised that it doesn't handle asynchronous throw:

```
var Promise = require("promise"); // also tried require("bluebird") here

function asyncThrow()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            throw new Error("Not handled!");
        })
    });
}

asyncThrow()
    .then(function() {
        console.log("resolved");
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("rejected");
    });
```

During this code execution node.js exists with unhanded exception (I expected this behavior).

Also I've tried "domain" based error handling:

```
var Promise = require("promise"); // also tried require("bluebird") here
var domain = require("domain");

function asyncThrow()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var d = domain.create();
        d.on("error", reject);
        d.run(function() {
            process.nextTick(function() {
                throw new Error("Not handled!");
            })
        });
    });
}

asyncThrow()
    .then(function() {
              console.log("resolved");
          },
          function() {
              console.log("rejected");
          })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("catch-rejected");
    });
```

This code behavior is much better but as expected - 'reject' function is called.

So the questions are:

1. How can I force "catch-reject" function call when handling asynchronous code?
2. Whether this approach gives significant performance penalty?
3. May be you can suggest better way to handle such exceptions?

Comment: Why do you use `process.nextTick()` to throw the exception? You leave the promise scope with that in the first example. Hence it is not caught.

Comment: @Sirko This is emulation of behavior of for example network interaction. When connection is lost exception is thrown.

Comment: Have you considered using `denodify()` to convert your async calls to promises as well?

Comment: @Sirko As I see in source code of denodify it doesn't do any magic - it just a call wrapper.

Comment: A promise library can only catch exceptions that are thrown within functions it calls directly or functions they call directly.  No promise library can catch an exception thrown in some other async callback.  So, when the exception is thrown in the `nextTick()` callback, the promise library cannot catch it.  You would have to either catch it yourself or promisify that specific function (which replaces the callback with one the promise library manages and thus is can then catch the exception).  This is just a reality/limitation of how Javascript works and an important aspect to understand.

Comment: So, you solve this problem generally, but promisifying all async operations you interface with (not using native callbacks for them).  This then allows the promise library to catch exceptions in those async callbacks.  Or, of course in some contexts, you can always use your own exception handlers and call `reject()` upon an exception which you could have done in this case.  No third party library should be throwing asynchronously from inside it's own async callback because that usually isn't catchable - unless it intends for the error to be a fatal error leading to shutdown.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree with you that it is bad design to not handle your exception by your own. But we have two options that are not avoidable - 1. library has error in some rare/very rare situation and don't handle everything, 2. client code has error and by mistake throw exception from callback that is not handled by library. This can cause crash node.js as if it is C/C++. Unfortunately world is not perfect.

Comment: I understand your dilemma, but if a third party piece of code throws from an async operation, that is a bug because of the way JavaScript and async works.  You will have to find a work around.  That is not something that promises can solve.  If a client callback throws, the library calling the client callback can catch that exception.

Comment: @DmitryPoroh: For that use case, domains seem to be the best solution. For everything else, you should not need them.

Comment: @Bergi I also don't see anything better. I will try performance and come back with results. But also it would be good to have seamless error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.denodeify(fn)](https://github.com/then/promise#promisedenodeifyfn) to achieve this.

```
var Promise = require("promise"); 

function asyncThrow()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Denodify the process.nextTick function
        var nextTick = Promise.denodeify(process.nextTick)
        // Utilize nextTick and return the promise
        return nextTick.then(function() {
            throw new Error("Not handled!");
        })
    });
}

asyncThrow()
    .then(function() {
        console.log("resolved");
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("rejected");
    });
```

This will result in the `.catch()` function being called.

Comment: This is not the solution because we also use third-party calls. We can't control them. For example we use libraries that are use networking stack (sip.js for example) and we can't force this library to use promises but like to wrap them around.

Comment: Ah, I see - then maybe the domain approach is the better solution.

Comment: domain approach would be ok if there was way to call catch-rejected. Performance is also unknown (I haven't run performance tests for this solution).